# With HTTPS-only mode in Firefox, may I still need HTTPS Eveywhere addon?

Tags: tls, http, firefox, browser-extensions

Firefox has a built-in toggle in settings to enforce [HTTPS-Only mode](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/11/17/firefox-83-introduces-https-only-mode/). When enabled, the browser attempts to redirect to HTTPS every time and, if fails, blocks access to the website in the same way that it blocks access when, e.g., the SSL certificate is invalid etc. The mode ensures that only secure connections come through.

Please note this passage from the attributions sections in the end of the blog post:

> We also want to acknowledge the work of our friends at the EFF, who pioneered a similar approach in HTTPS Everywhere’s EASE Mode. It’s a privilege to work with people who are passionate about building the web we want: free, independent and secure.

When I have the HTTPS-only option turned on in Firefox, may I still benefit from having HTTPS Everywhere add-on installed somehow, or is it completely redundant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Firefox's HTTPS-only mode blocks *all* unencrypted requests by default. The HTTPS Everywhere plugin blocks *some* unencrypted requests by default. Therefore if you're using HTTPS-only mode (and not just mindlessly clicking "continue" every time it displays a warning), HTTPS everywhere is entirely redundant.

HTTPS-everywhere may be preferable for some users precisely because it does *not* block all unencrypted requests (by default), only those on sites it has previously identified as HTTPS-compatible. This may result in fewer warnings about blocked sites, and a smaller risk of [alarm fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alarm_fatigue) causing users to bypass the warning in the event of an actual attack. If you've already decided to eschew insecure connections entirely though, such discretion is unnecessary.